# Installed module not found in Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, module, titanium, appcelerator

I am having troubles using a module I have added to Titanium. I followed the official directions to install a module (more specifically this module: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/udp/mobile/android):

- I have installed the ti.udp-android-2.1.2.zip file via help>Install Mobile Module
- Then I added the ti.udp module to the tiapp.xml (since it was directly found and could be selected from the list, I assume the install of the module was successful).
- I load the module with

`var UDP = require('ti.udp');`

Every time I start the application, I get the error:

> Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: ti.udp

*update*
Image of the tiapp.xml:

[image]

Comment: Did you ever have any luck getting this to work on android Consec i am also having issues getting it to work? thanks

Comment: I have never been able to make titanium find the globally installed modules. However, when I tried to install it only for one project (as described here: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.0/#!/guide/Using_a_Module-section-30082372_UsingaModule-Installingamoduleforasingleproject), titanium did find the module.

Answer (score 1):

Please go to tiapp.xml and see whether the module is being shown there.I don't think that your module added in tiapp.xml

Thanks

Comment: I have indeed added the module in the tiapp.xml (that what I meant with adding it to the manifest, I will change it) from a list with all installed modules.

Comment: Ok do one thing delete the old build clean the project and install the app again and let me know if u still face same problem

Comment: I have cleaned the project and rebuilt it, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Test the module in some new project

Comment: Also in a new project, the module can not be found. One strange thing that I always encounter when changing de modules of a project is the general error:
[ERROR] :  Build process exited with code 1
[ERROR] :  Project failed to build after 575ms
Only when deleting the <modules></modules> part, rebuilding the project and then again adding the <modules></modules> part and rebuilding the project I can compile the project. I don't know if it has something to do with this? Thanks for your help already

Comment: Is there a folder in your project named module as shown in the picture(http://imgur.com/4fhOu7J) ? The folder will be created only when your module installed properly.

Comment: I have indeed the modules folder as you described. Here you can see my folder structure and the relevant part in the tiapp.xml: http://imgur.com/yuc3zFx

Comment: Please read the readme file from https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/udp/mobile/ios. May be it can help you

Answer (score 1):

Your modules should be installed under `%User%/AppData/Roaming/Titanium/modules`

You can also verify what is your titanium sdk path in TitaniumStudio Window->Preference->Platform

I suspect that the tiapp.xml gets the modules from the Titanium Path, but the build will look for it in the User's path. That's why you do see it in the editor, but can't build